# Validation on Opportunity

Tags: apex, community, configuration

I am trying to write validation on Opportunity.
For Shipping Contact and Billing Contact need to be mandatory at 90% or above Probability.
Here is my validation rule

```
Probability >= 0.9 && AND(ISBLANK( Billing_Contact__c), ISBLANK(Shipping_Contact__c ))
```

But it's not working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give this a go..

it checks if the probability is >= 90% and if either billing or shipping contact is blank, throw an error..

```
AND(
  Probability >= 0.9 ,
  OR(
    ISBLANK( Billing_Contact__c), 
    ISBLANK(Shipping_Contact__c )
  )
)
```

Comment: Working Perfect @Vamsi

Answer (score 0):

Change your condition from AND to OR

```
Probability >= 0.9 && OR(ISBLANK( Billing_Contact__c), ISBLANK(Shipping_Contact__c ))
```

It should definitely work.